# Test class for standardsetcontroller

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I only have 30% code coverage.

```
public class MassDelete {
    public list<account> accs {get;set;}
    public MassDelete(apexpages.StandardSetController cont){
        string[] fields=new string[]{'name','industry','rating','phone'};
            cont.addfields(fields);
        accs=new list<account>();
        accs=(list<account>)cont.getselected();
    }
    public pagereference deletes(){
        delete accs;
        pagereference p=new pagereference('/search/UndeletePage');
        return p;
    }
}
```

test class:

```
@isTest
public class MassDeleteTest {    
    testmethod static void testme(){
        list<account> accs=new list<account>();
        account a=new account(name='Test Account');
        insert a;
        account a2=new account(name='account 2');
        insert a2;
        accs.add(a);
        accs.add(a2);
        test.startTest();
        pagereference pref=page.massDeleteAcc;
        test.setCurrentPage(pref);
        apexpages.standardsetcontroller std=new apexpages.StandardSetController(accs);
        std.setselected(accs);
        MassDelete obj=new Massdelete(std);
        test.stopTest();            
    }
}
```

Comment: add obj.deletes(); after MassDelete obj=new Massdelete(std); that will cover deletes method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call addFields from a `test method`. This is one of the very few cases where we just need to check `Test.isRunningTest`.

```
public class MassDelete {
public list<account> accs {get;set;}
public MassDelete(apexpages.StandardSetController cont){
    string[] fields=new string[]{'name','industry','rating','phone'};
        if(!test.isRunningTest()){
            cont.addfields(fields);
        }
    accs=new list<account>();
    accs=(list<account>)cont.getselected();
}
public pagereference deletes(){
    delete accs;
    pagereference p=new pagereference('/search/UndeletePage');
    return p;
}}
```

Try the above code your existing test will run fine.

Comment: @manid test.isrunningtest() usually comes in practice, when you want to conditionally restrict execution of certain Apex code blocks, based on whether they are being invoked from a test class or not.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your answer when adding explanation. It does not belong in the comments.